# JQuery DataTable columns() function undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

Trying to use Jquery DataTable plugin, calling api function

> column()

on datatable object  errors  out

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Created plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/LymRnduvhXHYfiqeDio6?p=preview
 my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var table=$('#myTable').dataTable( {
         "scrollX": true,
         "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
       });
  table.column(3).search('1998').draw();
});
```

call to function columns on table object errors out, api link http://datatables.net/reference/api/column()

what is wrong in my code? I am using the 1.10.2 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the api reference you need to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    });
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.column(3).search('1998').draw();
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MW8TnPgidv2AaoDdGaEk?p=preview)

[API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/)

> The API can be accessed through the following methods:
>
> ```
> $( selector ).DataTable();
> $( selector ).dataTable().api();
> new $.fn.dataTable.Api( selector );
> ```

Comment: Thank you it worked, var table = $('#example').DataTable();  should be  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

Comment: @ArunP  Johny it is not wokring for me. same issue continued. using jquery datatable 1.9

Comment: Thank you, I was fighting this for a while.  I missed the whole upper case lower case.